# Parallel threads calling in ASP.net 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading

*One customer arriving at the landing page would then consume 5 threads. One the main thread the request is getting serviced and then 4 separate threads from the ASP thread pool to serve the four parallel calls. In such a case, if 20 people arrive at the landing page all the available threads will be finished and the 21st person will wait 3 seconds until any thread starts working on this person's request.*

I am facing issue to achieve this task. But confuse where to start It can be done by multi threading and parallel calling of threads in ASP.net 4.

Anyone have any good resource article or sample about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [asynchronous ASP.NET pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).